# Npm install does not includes all files of a private package

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

I have a package placed in a private GitLab repository. But whenever I try to install this package, after installation, it does not include files that it contains. Only a single file index.tsx gets included.

my original package files:
[image]

And its source folder contains all the source code files
[image]

After I install the package I only get index.tsx file.

[image]

how to solve this problem

Comment: Is the screenshot from the Package in the Registry or the Repository you storing the source code it in?

Comment: it is from the repository in which the source code for the package is written

Comment: I edited the post and included another screenshot for a better perspective.

Comment: The pin down the issue, it would help to find out if the files are in the uploaded package at all. You can do that in GitLab checking the menu -> Package and Registries -> Package Registry . Choose your Package and download the tgz.

Comment: there are no packages when I go to the packages and registry section